# Parse Laravel JSON object in Javascript throwing error

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

Laravel code :

```
$teachers = Teachers::where('possessed_by_community', $communityId)->pluck('teacher_name');

return view('pages.show_add_teachers', [
    'teachers'  => $teachers
]);
```

Then in client side I tried :

```
var teachers = "<?php echo json_encode($teachers) ?>" ;
teachers = JSON.parse(teachers);
console.log(teachers);
```

In webconsole I get :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

In firefox debugger :

[image]

Comment: use single quotes instead `var teachers = '<?= json_encode($teachers) ?>';`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, that solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes instead `var teachers = '<?= json_encode($teachers) ?>';`

or don't use quotes at all, leaving out `JSON.parse(teachers);`.

```
var teachers = <?= json_encode($teachers) ?>;
console.log(teachers);
```

Though you must check `$teachers` is valid, string, null or array at all times.

Else it would become `var teachers = ;` and break.

Comment: `var teachers = '<?php echo json_encode($teachers) ?>' ;
teachers = JSON.parse(teachers);` worked

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jArray = @json($teachers);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.